# Организовать последовательный ввод текста из слов русского алфавита

Tags: freepascal

Добрый вечер! Не могу найти ошибку в коде.
Не могу понять, что не так, где ошибка...
Задание: "Организовать последовательный ввод текста из слов русского алфавита. Слова разделены пробелами, в конце строки-точка.Подсчитать количество слов в этой строке"

Код:

```
program slovo;   
var
   a: string;
   i, j: integer;
   t: boolean;
begin
     writeln('vvedite stroky');
     readln(a);
     i:=1;
     j:=0;
     while i<=length(a) do
     begin
        t:=false;
        while (a[i]<>' ') and (i<=length(a)) do
        begin
             t:=true;
             i:=i+1;
        end;
        if t=true then
        j:=j+1;
        i:=i+1;
     end;
     writeln('v ctrokekolichesvo slov=',j);
     readln;
end.
```

Программа работает, но при вводе любого количества слов, результат считает как 1...Помогите найти ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Не пишу на Pascal но примерное решение такое:

```
program slovo;   
var
   a: string;
   i, j: integer;
begin
     writeln('vvedite stroky');
     readln(a);
     a:=a + ' ' //что бы включить последнее слово
     i:=1;
     j:=0;
     while a[i] = ' ' do i := i + 1;//исключаем начальные пробелы если есть
     while i <= length(a) do
     begin
        //Ищем пробел  
        while (a[i] <> ' ') do i := i + 1;
        //Пробел найден значит закончилось слово - увеличиваем
        j := j + 1;
        while a[i] = ' ' do i := i + 1;//исключаем пробелы до следующего слова
     end;
     writeln('v ctrokekolichesvo slov=',j);
     readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот так правильно.

while работает до первого пробела.

```
 while (i<=length(a)) do
if a[i]=' ' then j:=j+1;
        i:=i+1;
     end;
```

Вот так будет работать.

Comment: а если в начале несколько пробелов и между словами?